# Magento some store configuration are 404

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, configuration, store-view

I have since years a Magento with around 20 stores for each country I sell my products. Recently, I don't know exactly when it started, I'm not able to access to the configuration for 3 stores I simply get a 404 when I switch the these store configuration. I have no problem with the other store.

Do you have any idea how can I debug this ? I tried to disable all the module but still can't access to the configuration...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: did you (I hope so ;)) install the patch SUPEE-6788. There where some security issues on how magento backend handles the user permissions for specific actions in the backend. Just af far shot. To provide detailed information on your problem I think we migt need more Information

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Yes I installed all available patches of course :) I tried to log error in  the admin controller (editAction function) because this function it's never called... but the url is : system_config/edit/section/general/website/can/store/fr/key/****

What information you need ? I spent a lot of time of this issue but since the controller is not called I don't know where I should looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Does someone have any idea ? :)

I installed all available patches of course, I tried to log error in the admin controller (editAction function) but this function it's never called... the url is : system_config/edit/section/general/website/can/store/fr/key/****

I spent a lot of time of this issue but since the controller is not called I don't know where I should looking for...